# Can Moq mock behavior in order to use an expressions methods parameters?

Tags: c#, moq

I've got a class with dozens of methods - i only really need to work with two of those methods and avoid dependency injection.

```
Task<List<ApplicationUser>> GetAllContractors(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
Task<ApplicationUser> FindByNameAsync(string normalizedUserName, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
```

My current attempt: (Works for all contractors easily enough since i don't need any parameter to take effect)

```
users.AddRange(await ManifestJsonLoader.LoadAsync<List<ApplicationUser>>("Mynamespace.sampleUsers.json"));
var userProviderMock = new Mock<IUserProvider>(MockBehavior.Strict);
userProviderMock.Setup(service => service.GetAllContractors(CancellationToken.None)).Returns(Task.FromResult(users));
userProviderMock.Setup(service => service.FindByNameAsync(It.Is<string>(name => users.FirstOrDefault(d => d.UserName == name) != null), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()));
```

I've looked for "moq method with parameters" but so far none of the results answered my question. Maybe i'm looking for the wrong keywords here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access invocation parameters in your mock method delegate by using the `Func` overload for `Returns()` to provide a lambda that accepts *exactly the same arguments* as the method you are mocking. Moq will pass any provided arguments through to your delegate.

**Example from the docs:**

```
// access invocation arguments when returning a value
mock.Setup(x => x.DoSomethingStringy(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns((string s) => s.ToLower());
```

> **Note 1** If you're mocking a method that has any default parameters you must provide these *explicitly*.
>
> **Note 2** Its worth mentioning the `Callback` option which is useful if you need to modify an object that isnt being returned, or you need to change your Mock behaviour based on the number of calls made.
>   https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#callbacks

There are good examples on the wiki page: https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart

Comment: Thanks. i'll try it out later this day and upvote accordingly